# Handlebarjs each loop different implementation

Tags: ember.js

i want to implement a different behavior of handlebar.js "each", first it iterate the half value of the total model. Second, on each iteration print 2 model values.

Answer (score 0):

Split your collection in half and do two `each` loops with different implementations.